# Using dashed option for other fields

Tags: biblatex

Some biblatex styles have a `dashed` option that replaces repeated authors' names with dashes. I want to do that for other fields besides the author.

Here's a (not so) minimal working example:

```
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{salaman9999,
 author  ={Redcliffe N. Salaman},
 year    =1985,
 title   ={The author here is shown only once.}}
@book{salaman1985,
 author  ={Redcliffe N. Salaman},
 year    =1985,
 title   ={The History and Social Influence of the Potato}}
@manual{ISO214:1976,
    Org-Short = {ISO},
    Organization = {International Standards Organization},
    Subtitle = {The organization here is shown multiple times},
    Title = {{ISO} 214:1976},
    Year = 1976}
@manual{ISO4:1997,
    Org-Short = {ISO},
    Organization = {International Standards Organization},
    Subtitle = {Information and documentation --- Rules for the abbreviation of title words and titles of publications},
    Title = {{ISO} 4:1997},
    Year = 1997}
@manual{ISO215:1986,
    Org-Short = {ISO},
    Organization = {International Standards Organization},
    Subtitle = {Documentation --- Presentation of contributions to periodicals and other serials},
    Title = {{ISO} 215:1986},
    Year = 1986}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{manual}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \usebibmacro{author/editor+others/organization}%
  \setunit{\labelnamepunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{title}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}}

\newbibmacro*{author/editor+others/organization}{%
    \ifboolexpr{%
        test {\ifnameundef{author}}
        and
        test {\ifnameundef{editor}}
    }
    {\usebibmacro{organization}}
    {\usebibmacro{author/editor+others}}}

\newbibmacro*{organization}{%
    \iflistundef{organization}
        {\global\undef\bbx@lasthash}
        {\usebibmacro{bbx:dashcheck}
           {\bibnamedash}
           {\usebibmacro{bbx:savehash}%
            \printlist[uppercase]{organization}}}%
}

\begin{document}
  \nocite{*}
  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

As you can see I redefined the `@manual` driver to print the organization when there is no author.

Then I tried defining an `organization` macro based on `authoryear`'s `author` and `editor` macros. I hoped the organization wouldn't be repeated, but instead would be replaced by a dash, like it happens with the author, but it didn't work:

[image: example]

So is there a way I could do that?

Thanks in advance,

Daniel

Comment: You could also give the institution as `author` of the norm (arguably it is responsible for the work). Then the distinction between `author` and `organisation` would be a non-problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the `bibmacro`s `bbx:dashcheck` and `bbx:savehash` use the `fullhash` field. However, `fullhash` does not exist if there is no name. Thus one has to replace the use of `fullhash` with a different value. To this end we check if the names (lists) for the organisation is the same at  the previous one.

We can change the  definition of the `bbx:dashchek` macro to

```
\renewbibmacro*{bbx:dashcheck}[2]{%
  \ifboolexpr{
    (test {\iflistequals{organization}{\bbx@lasthash}}
    or
    test {\iffieldequals{fullhash}{\bbx@lasthash}}
    )
    and
    not test \iffirstonpage
    and
    (
       not bool {bbx@inset}
       or
       test {\iffieldequalstr{entrysetcount}{1}}
    )
  }
    {#1}
    {#2}}
```

and then define the `organisation` macro as

```
\newbibmacro*{organization}{%
    \iflistundef{organization}
        {\global\undef\bbx@lasthash}
        {\usebibmacro{bbx:dashcheck}
           {\bibnamedash}
           {\savelist{organization}{\bbx@lasthash}%
            \printlist[uppercase]{organization}}}%
}
```

Given that we use  the internal `\bbx@lasthash` the definitions should be wrapped by `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother`.

With the two modification above we obtain:

[image]

Comment: The problem with this is that `sortinithash` really only compares the very first character (the initial) and so several institutions with the same first letter will be treated as if they are the same.

Comment: Ah, I was already getting excited about this, but @moewe is right, very different organizations are shown as the same as long as the first character is the same. What now? :/

Comment: Indeed. So one can check that the value of the list `organisation` is the same as what saved in `\bbx@lasthash` (I  have edited the solution accordingly).

Comment: Amazing! You're the man, thank you so much. :)